# Action on Google rejected because of Digital Transactions API

Tags: transactions, action, actions-on-google

An Action on Google I was working on got rejected by the AoG Review Team stating that I need to integrate Transactions API or Digital Purchase API.

The AoG in question basically leads the users to a products-listing page in which the users can choose a product and purchase it.

Is `Transactions API` or `Digital Purchase API` really required in this case? If yes, which of the two should I integrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved the issue for now. `Digital Purchase API` is only required if you specifically mention words like 'purchase' 'shop on the link' etc., ie. content that directly implies that you can purchase/make a transaction through the links. Thanks to the support team who helped me with this.

So, I reworded/rephrased the content to something like 'Click the link to know more' instead of 'Click to shop online' and my action got approved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the Assistant is used to get to a product listing page, and then can purchase something from that page, then you need to use the Transactions API to manage that purchase.

The Digital Purchase API is more used for things like in-game purchases, getting subscriptions to features in your Action, etc.